# how to restart wampserver 2.0 (powered by anaska)

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2003, wamp

I wish I didn't have a server running WAMP but I do. On Linux I'd just do `sudo service restart httpd` or `apache2` or whatever. But with WAMP? I have no clue.

There's an icon in the notification area of the taskbar that, when clicked on, shows a menu:

[image]

If I click "Stop All Services" or "Put Offline" and then visit http://127.0.0.1/ in Firefox I still see the website being served up.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065551/569976 says to do `cd C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/bin; httpd --start`. Doing so gives me this error:

```
[Tue Sep 29 17:06:11 2015] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I also tried `httpd --restart` and got the same error.

When I do Start -> Run -> services.msc I don't see an Apache service. I see a wampapache service, however it's status is not "Started".

When I do `netstat -a -b` I see this:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    MYSERVER:http           MYSERVER.MYCOMPANY.local:0   LISTENING       4168
  [httpd.exe]
```

That's cool. I have no idea where that httpd.exe file lives however. I would have thought it was living at `C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/bin` but I have no idea.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure when you stopped the service and went to the browser you weren't being shown a cached page? Try "stop all services" in the menu and clearing your browser cache before trying again. Did you do that netstat command after restarting the service? C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/bin; httpd --start looks like it would start the service, not stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to start and stop Apache and or MySQL using WAMPServer

From the menu system, which is wampmanager :

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume service
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Stop service
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart service

wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume service
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop service
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Restart service
```

These menu options even enable and disable themselves depending on whether the service is currently running or not, so by looking at the availability you can see if a service is currently running or not.

Alternatively if you like to use the command line :

```
net start wampapache
net start wampmysqld

net stop wampapache
net stop wampmysqld
```

of course if you are using the 64bit WAMPServer and therefore the 64 bit Apache, the commands will be

```
net start wampapache64
net start wampmysqld64

net stop wampapache64
net stop wampmysqld64
```

The error message of course means that you have configured Apache incorrectly. Check you config changes.

The `Put Online` menu option is irrelevant, in this case, as all that does is amend the `httpd.conf` file to change the allowed access to your server, from "Offline" just local access and "Online", allow from any ip.

Comment: The `net` commands don't work for me (wamp on windows 10): > `net stop wampapache
The service name is invalid.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.`. That last command won't work either. Using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @Julien Did you start the cmd windows using "Run as Administrator"? If you did, maye you are using the 64 bit wampserver so it would be `net stop wampapache64`

Comment: You are right. Running as administrator and using `wampapache64` instead of `wampapache` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

- Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type "**services.msc**" > OK
- Find "wampapache" & "wampmysqld", right click on it/them > Start/Stop/Restart

  [image: Restart Apache]